# Adwords - ClientLogin authentication method is now deprecated and will be removed in the future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, google-ads-api

I am using ruby-on-rails to work with google-adwords-api. **Until today my application was successfully working** retrieving the information I needed using the API.
Today it stopped working and in the console I see the following warning:

> ClientLogin authentication method is now deprecated and will be
>   removed in the future. Consider migration to OAuth2. See
>   'https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps' for
>   more details.

And then the following exception is fired:

> Authorization failed.  Server message: {   "error" : "invalid_grant" }

Here are the gems I am using to work with the API:

```
gem "google-adwords-api", "~> 0.9.3"
gem 'google-api-client'
```

The adwords_api.yml is:

```
---
:authentication:
  :method: OAUTH2
  :oauth2_client_id: ***.apps.googleusercontent.com
  :oauth2_client_secret: ***
  :oauth2_callback: http://...
  :developer_token: ***
  :user_agent: ***
  :oauth2_token:
    :access_token: ***
    :refresh_token: ***
:service:
  :environment: PRODUCTION
:connection:
  :enable_gzip: false
:library:
  :log_level: INFO
```

I checked the link from the warning message but didn't find which changes I should make in my code.

From the call-stack (and also from the settings in the yml above) looks like OATH2 is already used here. I found that a call to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` is done and the response with status=400 has body `{   "error" : "invalid_grant" }`

**Remark**: I don't use two steps verification.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case the problem was that the the token has been [created](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup) using a google account which was recently deleted.

Hope this answer will save your time if you face this problem.